# Code in JSP file is executed couple times

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I don't understand why my code in JSP file is executed three times. 
I'm using Tomcat 9.0.12 configured in Intellij IDE.

Code in JSP

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
</head>
<body>
<%! String foo = "foo";
    String bar = "bar";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();%>
<% sb.append(foo).append(bar).toString();%>
<%=sb%>
</body>
</html>
```

And after running Tomcat server result in page is:

[image]

Comment: You really shouldn't use code fragments like that in JSP.

Comment: that's my first steps in JSP.

Comment: That style of using JSP has been considered a bad practice for at least a decade, you may want to consider if your study material is up-to-date.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Could you suggest sources with up-to-date approach to JSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add it in separation like following:

```
<% 
    String foo = "foo";
    String bar = "bar";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(foo);
    sb.append(bar);
%>
<%= sb.toString();%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaration <%! %> will be called only once therefore by each call you append additional "foobar" to the same StringBuilder